# How to add 'Total Orders' Count column to Order Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, php

**Brief**

Add a column to the **Order Grid**, entitled "Total Orders" that shows the total count of orders for each customer.

**Problem**

I've taken what I've understood from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13747166). This has successfully managed to create the desired column but without any results. I believe the error lies somewhere within part 2 of my implementation.

**Where I'm at**

1 - Override created **/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php**

2 - Added below to **_prepareCollection()**

```
$alias = 'subselect';
$subselect = Mage::getModel('Varien_Db_Select', 
    Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')
    )->from('sales_flat_order_grid', array(
            'customer_id as s_customer_id', 
            'count(*) as total_orders')
    )->group('customer_id');

$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinInner(array($alias => $subselect), 
        "{$alias}.s_customer_id = main_table.customer_id");
```

3 - Added below to **_prepareColumns()**

```
$this->addColumn('total_orders', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Orders'),
    'index' => 'total_orders',
    'filter_index' => 'total_orders',
));
```

Comment: its working fine

Answer (score 1):

The one thing stopping this from working was my positioning of the code in Step 2.

I tried added my code in step 2 after the line containing return **parent::_prepareCollection();**

**This is how step 2 should look in its entirety**

```
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    //Added prepare for Total Orders
    $alias = 'subselect';
    $subselect = Mage::getModel('Varien_Db_Select', 
        Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')
        )->from('sales_flat_order_grid', array(
                'customer_id as s_customer_id', 
                'count(*) as total_orders')
        )->group('customer_id');

    $collection->getSelect()
        ->joinInner(array($alias => $subselect), 
            "{$alias}.s_customer_id = main_table.customer_id");
    //Added prepare for Total Orders

    return parent::_prepareCollection();

    }
```

Comment: This will not work on guest orders, since there is no customer_id listed for a guest order.